# Populate text in one textfield from text in another

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4

Working on an experiment on the iPad. Tried some variations on how to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly...

I tap a UIButton on my MainViewController and a TextEntryModule is added to the view. TextEntryModule is its own class (for multiple instantiation) and it contains a UITextView called TextEntry (this all works at the moment).

I tap on the TextEntry UITextView and it brings up the keyboard and another view (located in MainViewController) with a UITextView called TextPreview. (this also works at the moment).

The part I'm having trouble with is synching the two UITextViews. The idea being that when I type into TextEntry, the text in TextPreview will also be updated.

Outlets are linked properly for the text fields, but I think I'm missing something "obvious":

```
TextEntryModule *tm = (AnnotationModule *)currentModule;
TextPreview.text = tm.TextEntry.text
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextView: [delegate.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextViewDelegate)

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
```

Then assign it the value of the other textview in this method.

### Edit

```
@interface MainViewController <UITextViewDelegate> {
   ...
}
...
@end
```

Then you implement this method in the implementation file of MainViewController

```
@implementation MainViewController

//More code

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    TextEntryModule *tm = (AnnotationModule *)currentModule;
    TextPreview.text = tm.TextEntry.text
}
@end
```

Then you will have to set the TextEntryModule object's delegate to `self` since the controller now conform to the protocol and can "act" upon this notification.

Comment: Yeah, I am actually using UITextView, not field... Mixed them up when typing the post and I've updated that. I'm not sure where to put the delegates though. On the view in the instantiated class or the view in the main view?

Comment: @Eric: Updated answer, let me know if something miss or I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was a lot closer than I'd thought! Following the above, I've got the text moving from one view to the other appropriately when the keyboard pops, but textViewDidChange doesn't seem to be doing anything when I type.

Comment: I was able to get the effect I wanted for this round without textViewDidChange. I just reversed the process outline above and it worked like a charm. The great thing about this project is that I'm able to refine it later and have focused items to research more in-depth. Thanks again!

Comment: @Eric: No problem, I have never tried using the delegate myself, but often it is worth looking at the delegates and see when the method is invoked. However did you try to just log some text in the other methods which you can implement when conforming to the delegate? Anyway good that it helped you:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to become a UITextFieldDelegate and monitor when text changes in the one field and then update the other field. Take a look at the documentation on it.